Given a closed subspace, does there exist an injective operator which the subspace is invariant?
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B\subset H$ a (proper) closed subspace. Does there exists a nontrivial (not identity) injective linear continuous operator $T$ such that $T(B)=B$? If there is, can we explicitly construct such $T$?
The projection operator on subspace does leave the subspace invariant but not injective. I am thinking about something like unitary operator but not sure how to proceed.

If $P$ is the projection onto $B$, then $P + \frac{1}{2} (I - P)$ is such an operator. There are plenty more (in the way you stated this question, even $\frac{1}{2} I$ would be one). Do you want more conditions on $T$?
